# Disabling Firefox and Chrome spell checking in iframe-based text editors

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, gwt, designmode

There is a lot of info around about how to disable spell checking in html `textarea` element by using `spellcheck='false'`. However to have text area with more advanced capabilities, one must use `iframe` with `designMode = "on"` (see e.g. [this page](http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/02/web-based-content-editor-using-iframe/), this is a way that RichTextArea is implemented in GWT) and I couldn't find a single post on that topic.

It turns out that Firefox detects such advanced text areas and enables its spell checking in them. You can see it live by visiting [this page](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~RichTextArea) from Firefox/Chrome and entering some content to text field. If you inspect html source code with e.g. Firebug, you'll see no `textarea` tag, yet FF spell checking is still active. The only way I managed to disable it was setting `designMode` to `off` but... I need it to be `on`.

The question is: **Is there any possibility to disable FF spell checking for iframe-based text areas, without setting designMode = "off"?**

Comment: I discovered that adding `spellcheck="false"` to the `<body>` of the text area's `iframe` (i.e. `<body spellcheck="false">`) does the trick - FF turns spellchecking off. Now to find a way to get the attribute there ...

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. See the answer of Blake, he discovered it too. Unfortunately it doesn't work with Chrome (it's probably a Chrome bug from what I read in bug report, because it is supposed to work).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set `spellcheck="false"` onto the `body` element in the iframe. Works [here](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~RichTextArea) in FF.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Blake. It works like a charm in Firefox indeed! But it turned out that the same problem is with Chrome and your solution doesn't help in case of Chrome :(. I know it's not nice from my side,  but I cannot accept your answer right now because I'm hoping someone will find good answer also for Chrome (I extended the question).

Comment: It seems that there is a bug issued for it in chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40509 :/.

Comment: The issue was fixed: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40509#c13

The `spellcheck="false"` also works in my version of Chome