# Red typo lines on html page when editing with Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

For my chrome extension, I'm editing the body of the document of the HTML on a web page with jQuery. Every time I do so, a squiggly red-typo underline show up on some of the words on the page as if I was in Microsoft Word. How do I remove these underlines?

My function is used in highlighting text from the page:

```
function highlight(colour) {
    document.designMode = "on";
    document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    document.designMode = "off";
}
```

Screenshot from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4ei4454ycho1a8/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-03%20at%207.33.17%20PM.png?dl=0

Not a duplicate of: [Disabling Firefox and Chrome spell checking in iframe-based text editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391766/disabling-firefox-and-chrome-spell-checking-in-iframe-based-text-editors)

- The typo underlines appear on the body of an html page, not an i-framed text editor

Comment: Edit the question and add the page URL, the code you use, and a screenshot.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you, I edited my post and added my function with a screenshot of the output I'm seeing.

Comment: Disagree with your not-a-duplicate assessment. It does not matter if it's iframed or not.